# Converting Session $data Into An Array?

Tags: php, session, serialization

In the write function for a session save handler $data is passed in a format like this:

> test|a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:3:"bar";}session|a:2:{s:10:"isLoggedIn";b:1;s:8:"clientId";s:5:"12345
>   ";}

Is there a way to convert that into the proper array which would be:

```
array
(
    'test' => array
    (
        'foo' => 'bar'
    )
    'session' => array
    (
        'isLoggedIn' => true
        'clientId' => '12345'
    )
)
```

I tried passing that into unserialize but I get an error of:

> unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 95 bytes

and it just return false.

Comment: What does the session save handler function look like?

Comment: Please properly serialize the string, don't use some custom function.

Comment: If this is the original string, then it's no wonder unserialize fails. It's malformed. Don't use malformed inputs.

Comment: How does the write function look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [session_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php)

Comment: ok, well that does what I want for the write however is there a way to convert an array into a valid session string for the read (note that I am wanted to store the session as an array in mongodb to be able to better debug session data if I need to)

Comment: There is some good examples [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php)

Answer (score 8):

about the other answer. the description for session_decode is "session_decode() decodes the session data in data, setting variables stored in the session. " that doesn't sound like it does what you need.. and also it will always return bool after parsing a string.

on the other hand, if the string you provided as an example had a mistake, the space after "12345" (and it looks like a mistake because in front of it you can see that the following value should be a string with the length 5) you can use this function:

```
function unserialize_session_data( $serialized_string ) 
{
    $variables = array();
    $a = preg_split( "/(\w+)\|/", $serialized_string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );

    for( $i = 0; $i<count($a); $i = $i+2 )
    {
        if(isset($a[$i+1]))
        {
                $variables[$a[$i]] = unserialize( $a[$i+1] );
        }
    }
    return( $variables );
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this won't work if there are pipe characters already in the session data.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. As for |s. I replace pipes before the session encode process or it fails to save properly. After decoding I replace the replacement.

Comment: You saved me friend (y)

Comment: After 5 hours of searching finally this one worked , thank you very much